# Paypal callback not validating

Tags: html, paypal, callback

Okay so I have got my paypal buttons working properly. Everything looks great, but I have some problems with the IPN system.

I have the code that paypal provided [here](https://www.x.com/instant-payment-notification-4), but when I send an IPN from my developer account, it does not validate the IPN properly. Every time it reads the receipt as *INVALID*. What do I need to do for it to validate the IPN properly?

Comment: Debug your curl, to see if it: actually receives anything, is able to connect to paypal or contains an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be exposed to the client. Use IPN described here

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

you should copy code samples here to have it all on your back end:

https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

Comment: I implemented the code shown on the second link you gave me, but it is failing validation of the IPN (Step 3) in my PHP code.